# For loop in C++ stops after a single iteration w/ pointer variable

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

So first all I'll preface this with: I just started using c++.

I have a structure that I store the pointer to in an unordered_map, setting members' values in the struct pointer as I get them through my process. Then I no longer need them in a map so I transfer then to a vector and loop through them.

Though on the second loop, it outputs my index (`1`) but the next statement of making a local pointer var  for the struct at that index breaks it and the code terminates without any errors. since there are no errors then a try/catch doesn't give me anything either.

---

```cpp
// Wanted to create a structure to handle the objects easier instead
//  of multiple vectors for each property
struct appData {
    std::string id = "";
    std::string name = "";
    std::string vdf_file = "";
    std::string vdf_path = "";
};
```

---

```cpp
// Relevant parts of my main()
int main() {

  // Map that stores all the struct pointers
  std::unordered_map<std::string, appData*> appDatas;
  
  char memory[sizeof(appData)];
  void* p = memory;
  // New instance of appData
  appData *tempAppData = new(p) appData();
  tempAppData->appid = "86901";
  // Add tempAppData to map with string key
  appDatas["86901"] = tempAppData;

  ...

  std::vector<appData*> unhashed_appDatas;
  for (auto const& pair: appDatas) {
    unhashed_appDatas.push_back(pair.second);
  }

  ...
 
  for (unsigned int x = 0; x < unhashed_appDatas.size(); x++) {
    // Output index to see where it was messing up
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
!!  // This is where the issue happens on the second loop (see output)
    appData *thisAppData = unhashed_appDatas[x];
    std::string id = thisAppData->appid;
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
    /* ...
       Do more stuff below
    */
  }

  ...

  return 0;
}
```

---

```cpp
Terminal Output:
0               // Initial index of x
86901           // Id of first item
1               // New index of x on second loop before pointer var is created
                // Nothing more is printed and execution terminates with no errors
```

---

My knowledge of c++ is pretty lacking, started it couple days ago, so the few things within my knowledge I've tried: moving the `*thisAppData` variable outside of the loop, using a `for(var: vector) { ... }`, and a while loop. I can assume that the issue lies with the pointer and the local variable when inside the loop.
Any help/input about how I could better approach this or if there's an issue with my code would be appreciated :)

Edit: Changed code to use `.size()` instead of `sizeof()` per @Jarod42 answer, though main issue persists

Edit2: Turns out it was my own mess-up, imagine that. 4Am brain wasn't working too well- [posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65471459/7538975) regarding what I did incorrectly. Thanks to everyone who helped me

Comment: If your knowledge of c++ is lacking, using placement new on a buffer with automatic storage duration may not be the wisest approach.

Comment: please include a [mcve]

Comment: @EOF What would be a different approach so I can avoid doing that until I have more knowledge? I just looked up lile how to allocate memory for srtuct/string variable and went with an answer I commonly saw- though the sites did say the same thing, about it not being wise if you don't know much. I'm just trying to get this working and learn along the way by messing around with code.

Comment: Don't use manual memory management (don't use `new` / `delete`). Use standard containers like `std::vector`

Comment: You don't have to use **placement** new, you can use *regular* **new**. More sanely, you could use `std::unique_ptr`, or just plain objects if you're not using inheritance.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I have made the code more trimmed down

Comment: Notice: `datas` isn't correct in English.

Comment: I was already lost at the first line in main: `bb = aa.get()->childs;`  seems like the problem was elsewhere, though in general its better to either show the code (for `aa`) or remove it when it isnt relevant intstead of describe it in words

Comment: @jarod I have data from one source, and from 7 different sources I have collected many datas!  Plural-plural, bwahahahaha. (I kid)  OTOH, in that ST:TNG episode, time travel did result in multiple Datas... ;)

Comment: @EOF I used a "regular" `new` instead which seems to work, didn't know why I ended up using that other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of trial and error I have determined the issue (aside from doing things in a way I should, which I've since corrected) it was something I messed up on that caused this issue.

### TLDR:

Items wouldn't exist that I assumed did and tried to read files with a blank path and parse the contents that didn't exist.

---

### Explaination:

In the first loop, the data I was getting was a list of files from a directory then parsing a json-like file that contained these file names and properties associated with them. Though, the file list contained entries that weren't in this other data file (since I had no check if they existed) so it would break there.
Additionally in the last loop I would get a member from a struct that would be the path of a file to read, but it would be blank (unset) because it didn't exist in data file so `std::ifstream file(path);` would break it.
I've since implemented checks for each key and value to ensure it will no longer break because of that.

---

### Fixes:

Here are some fixes that were mentioned that I added to the code, which *did* help it work correctly in the end even if they weren't the main issue that I myself caused:

```cpp
// Thanks to @EOF:
// No longer "using placement new on a buffer with automatic storage duration"
// (whatever that means haha) and was changed from:
  char memory[sizeof(appData)];
  void* p = memory;
  appData *tempAppData = new(p) appData();
// To:
  appData *tempAppData = new appData();
```

```cpp
// Thanks to @Jarod42:
// Last for loop limit expression was corrected from:
  for (unsigned int x = 0; x < sizeof(unhashed_appDatas); x++) {
  } 
// To:
  for (unsigned int x = 0; x < unhashed_appDatas.size(); x++) {
  }
```

```cpp
// I am still using a map, despite comment noting to just use vectors
// (which I could have, but just would prefer using maps):
  std::unordered_map<std::string, appData*> appDatas;
// Instead of doing something like this instead (would have arguably have been easier):
  std::vector<std::string> dataKeys = { "1234" };
  std::vector<appData*>    appDatas = {   ...  };
  auto indx = find(dataKeys.begin(), dataKeys.end(), "1234");
  indx = (indx != dataKeys.end() ? indx : -1);
  if (indx == -1) continue;
  auto dataItem = appDatas[indx];
//
```

I appreciate everyone's assistance with my code

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` is the wrong tool here:

```
for (unsigned int x = 0; x < sizeof(unhashed_appDatas); x++) {
//                           ^^ wrong: give **static** size of the structure
// mainly 3 members (data, capacity, size), so something like `3*sizeof(void*)`
```

it should be

```
for (unsigned int x = 0; x < unhashed_appDatas.size(); x++) {
```

Comment: Seems I changed it to `sizeof` by accident when I was messing around with it and I have now updated my code to use `.size()`, thanks. Though the main issue still persists even so.

Comment: Your placement new is strange, but you show only the insertion which "works", not the second one...